# Load .Rda file / Twitter Authentication in OpenCPU with R

Tags: r, opencpu

I created a package which gets Twitter data with the twitteR package. But to do so it needs the authentication.
By now I created a .Rda file on my local system containing the Twitter handshake and placed the file in my package. But when I want to execute the function on OpenCPU it tells me:

```
Error: cannot open the connection

In call:
readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE)
```

So it seems that it can´t find the file.

- How can I load the .Rda file in OpenCPU?
- Can I add it to my package so that it is loaded when the package is loaded?
- Is there a better/easier way for the authentication process?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to include objects in an R package is by placing them in the `data` folder of your source package. See [writing R extensions 1.1.6](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages). The [appdemo](https://github.com/opencpu/appdemo) package also has some examples. If you want to automatically load the data when the package is loaded you need to set `LazyData: true` in your package `DESCRIPTION`.

The best way to design authentication depends on the design of your system. In public applications it makes sense that the client supplies the authentication credentials as a function argument. If you want your server to read credentials from disk somewhere, make sure you allow this file in the security policies, see section 3.5 of the [server manual](http://jeroenooms.github.io/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for you help. It got me a step further. In R I use the code    
<code> data(auth, envir=environment())
  registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)         </code>        

  When I run it locally it works finde. Lazyload loads the data and the
commands load it into the environment.
But when I call the function in the OpenCPU cloud I get the following error:
                              
<code>

Error: object 'twitCred' not found

In call:
inherits(oauth, "OAuth“) </code>

So it seems like it can´t find the object twitCred which is in the auth.Rda file.

Comment: Can you post your example code somewhere so I can help you debug the problem> Also it is conventional to give the data file the same name as the object, i.e. `twitCred.rda` contains an object `twitCred`.

Comment: After changing the name of the .rda file to twitCred, the function call seems to work. But now I have another problem: It does not show the created html in the main page. I uploaded my code to https://github.com/JulianHill/TimelineVieweR  The main page is in the directory /inst/www    It calls the R function, which creates the output index.html and places it in a div. But the div stay empty. Do you know why? I thing it is because of missing js files. So how should I set the paths or where to place the js files?